# does same image name but from different folder affect performance in web application?

Tags: html

i have lots of images in my web page with same name but in different folder like

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="pictures1" class="effect_1">
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/1/01/1/01.jpg" width="125" height="188"></div>
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/1/01/1/02.jpg" width="125" height="188"></div>
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/1/01/1/03.jpg" width="125" height="188"></div>
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/1/01/1/04.jpg" width="125" height="188"></div>
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/1/01/1/05.jpg" width="125" height="188"></div>
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/1/01/1/06.jpg" width="125" height="188"></div>
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/1/01/1/07.jpg" width="125" height="188"></div>
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/1/01/1/08.jpg" width="125" height="188"></div>
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/1/01/1/09.jpg" width="125" height="188"></div>
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/1/01/1/10.jpg" width="125" height="188"></div>
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/x.gif" width="125" height="188"></div>
 </div>

  <div id="pictures2" class="effect_2">
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/1/02/1/01.jpg" width="125" height="188"></div>
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/1/02/1/02.jpg" width="125" height="188"></div>
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/1/02/1/03.jpg" width="125" height="188"></div>
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/1/02/1/04.jpg" width="125" height="188"></div>
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/1/02/1/05.jpg" width="125" height="188"></div>
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/1/02/1/06.jpg" width="125" height="188"></div>
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/1/02/1/07.jpg" width="125" height="188"></div>
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/1/02/1/08.jpg" width="125" height="188"></div>
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/1/02/1/09.jpg" width="125" height="188"></div>
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/1/02/1/10.jpg" width="125" height="188"></div>
    <div><img src="pictures/sample/x.gif" width="125" height="188"></div>
 </div>

  ..................... up to 09/../../.jpg
</div>
```

there are lots of images in my page this is just for sample, when i run my application it takes too much time to load and suddenly crash...why?

Comment: What crashes? The browser I assume

Comment: You should probably debug with the Firebub plugins NET console...

Comment: You should close your <img /> tags

Comment: Maybe it's angry at your improperly closed `img` tags.

Comment: yes browser crashes,ohh img tags are not closed

Comment: ohh yes img tags are not closed.....

Comment: @Sumit are you serious? That cant be the bug.

Comment: even i close img tags it takes huge time to load

Answer (score 1):

What is the size (KB or MB) of each image?

If your images are to big it needs time for the browser to download them all.

The `width` and  the `height` you specify is for display reasons only.

e.g.
If you images is 3MB each (2000x2000 pixels) browser will download fist the image (3MB) and then display it in width/height you gave him.

Comment: images size is max 230 to 300 kb as it is being croped by editors using photoshop

Comment: you have 10 images in each block (without x.gif) and as you say you have 9 blocks. 9x10=90. 90x265=23850KB about 23MB (i take an average of 265KB per image). You page is big. It is normal to be slow

Comment: so how to optimize performance does using background-img instead of <img> tag will help me to optimize performance?

Comment: No it is the same. Browser has to download the image and use it as a background. You have to use thumbnails. You want to display you images in 125x188 so make you images in that size. I suggest even smaller thumbnails (about 90px width) an on click in thumbnail to show in popup the original image. See lightbox.

Comment: ok thanks for suggestion but actually i have done coding onClick event already as it was requirment by client img gets zoomed when clicked

Answer (score 0):

Do you only have this static html or is there any php or other code besides html? 
If there is, please provide it to us.

There shouldn't be any problems just loading quite small images only with html.
Tried it with another browser?

Comment: no my web page have only static html and i tried with all browser all takes too much time to load

Answer (score 0):

Having files in different locations will affect the linking of pages together and this why Paths are so important. Paths are used to create a link to a file located in a different folder than the current document. To do the linking you must specify the file correct location or path so that browsers can find it.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="pictures1" class="effect_1">
    <div><img src="/pictures/sample/1/01/1/01.jpg" width="125" height="188"><img /></div>
    <div><img src="/pictures/sample/1/01/1/02.jpg" width="125" height="188"><img /></div>
 </div>
  <div id="pictures2" class="effect_2">
    <div><img src="/pictures/sample/1/02/1/01.jpg" width="125" height="188"><img /></div>
    <div><img src="/pictures/sample/1/02/1/02.jpg" width="125" height="188"><img /></div>
</div>
```